# NameError: name 'writeword' is not defined (error in python)

Tags: python

```
dict={"key":"lock","kailas":"name boy","kerala":"city","kalyani":"name girl","bady":"horse"}
search_word = raw_input("enter a word")

if search_word in dict:
   print dict[search_word]
   print writeword(search_word)
else:
    Y = search_word[0]
    print Y
    print writeword(Y)
    for word in dict:
         if word[0]==Y:
            print "whether you want '"+word+"' this word"

def writeword(search_word ):
    with open("spast_history", 'w')as file:
        for item in search_word:
            file.write(str(item)+'\n')
```

---

I define function call it but still it show name error.Give any solution to solve this.

Comment: Define the function before calling it. Python code is executed from top to bottom. Or use it within another function body (then it will only be looked up upon execution of the function).

Answer (score 0):

Python is executed iterative form the interpreter. But the function write_word is defined after your function call. The best way would be wrap the code block in a function and execute it at the bottom of your file. Your file should look like this.

```
def main():
    dict={"key":"lock","kailas":"name boy","kerala":"city","kalyani":"name girl","bady":"horse"}
    search_word = raw_input("enter a word")

    if search_word in dict:
       print dict[search_word]
       print writeword(search_word)
    else:
       Y = search_word[0]
       print Y
       print writeword(Y)
    for word in dict:
       if word[0]==Y:
           print "whether you want '"+word+"' this word"

def writeword(search_word):
    with open("spast_history", 'w')as file:
        for item in search_word:
            file.write(str(item)+'\n')

main()
```

Note you can also define the dict outside of the method.